# When flipping a coin 12 times, what is the probability that, at some point after the first flip, the number of heads equals the number of tails?

Tags: combinatorics

The solution says to let $F_{n,k}$ be the number of ways to flip the coin $n$ times such that the positive difference between the number of heads and the number of tails is equal to $k$. Then we should find a recurrence $F_{n,k} = F_{n-1,k-1} + F_{n-1,k+1}$. I am not sure 1) how to derive this recurrence relation and 2) how we can use this to solve this problem. The correct answer is suppose to be  $\boxed{\dfrac{793}{1024}}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have an idea but it does not involve your method. I would state it only if you find it of any use.

Comment: The [Reflection Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)) provides a fairly easy way to answer the question, though it does not use your recursion.  Reflecting over the future path starting from the first time the number of Heads exceeds the number of Tails, you see that the probability that this ever happens is twice the probability that the string of $12$ ends with more Heads than Tails.  That is easily computed and the answer is what you say.

Comment: @lulu Would that be some form of the catalan numbers?

Comment: Certainly related, not sure if there is a simple direct relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If after the $n$th toss, the positive difference between heads and tails is $k$. Also, if $H_n$ denotes the number of Heads after $n$ tosses, then either $H_n=H_{n-1}$ and $ T_n=T_{n-1}+1$, or $H_n=H_{n-1}+1$ and $ T_n=T_{n-1}$. This is just saying that the $n$th toss was either H or T. This implies that $$k=|H_n-T_n|=|H_{n-1}-T_{n-1}|\pm1=k_{n-1}\pm1$$ This says that the positive difference between H and T on the ($n-1$)th toss was either $k-1$ or $k+1$. So the number of ways to flip a coin such that the positive difference $F_{n,k}$ between H and T is $k$ after $n$ tosses is made up of a combination of $F_{n-1,k-1}$ and $F_{n-1,k+1}$.

---

Why is this combination simply addition? Well each method in $F_{n-1,k-1}$ and $F_{n-1,k+1}$ correspond to exactly one way in $F_{n,k}$. To see this, choose any way in $F_{n,k}$. It is a sequence $$HHTHTTH\cdots THT$$This has $|H-T|=k$. This means either $H=T+k$ or $T=H+k$. If you remove the final $T$, then this corresponds to a chain with either $H=T+k-1$ or $T-1=H+k$. These are ways from $F_{n-1,k-1}$ and $F_{n-1,k+1}$ respectively. Also the opposite chain, $$TTHTHHT\cdots HTH$$ is also in $F_{n,k}$, and also comes from either $F_{n-1,k-1}$ or $F_{n-1,k+1}$. So in the case when $H=T+k$, you get $2$ chains from two chains in $F_{n-1,k-1}$ and $F_{n-1,k+1}$, and similarly in the case $T=H+k$. From this you can conclude that every chain in $F_{n,k}$ is in one-to-one correspondence with either a chain from $F_{n-1,k-1}$ or a chain from $F_{n-1,k+1}$, with no chain from either of these left out.

So $$F_{n,k}=F_{n-1,k-1}+F_{n-1,k+1}$$

---

You want the probability of landing in a way from one of $$F_{1,0},F_{2,0},\cdots F_{12,0}$$Notice that there are no ways in $F_{n,0}$ if $n$ is odd. The required probability is $$P=\frac{F_{2,0}}{2^2}+\frac{F_{4,0}}{2^4}+\cdots +\frac{F_{12,0}}{2^{12}}$$Using the recurrence relation, we have that $$\require{cancel}\begin{align}F_{n,0}&=F_{n-1,1}+\cancel{F_{n-1,-1}}_{\text{since k must be positive}}\\&=F_{n-2,0}+F_{n-2,2}\\&=F_{n-4,0}+F_{n-4,2}+F_{n-2,2}\end{align}$$
We can also find that  $$\begin{align}F_{n,k}&=F_{n-1,k-1}+F_{n-1,k+1}\\&=F_{n-2,k-2}+2F_{n-2,k}+F_{n-2,k+2}\end{align}$$
These two can be used to reduce things like $F_{12,0}$ down to things in terms of $F_{n,n}$, which is equal to $2$, or $F_{2,0}$, $F_{2,2}$, etc. It is quite cumbersome to calculate $P$. I believe this should give the correct answer though.

As an example of this process: $$F_{12,0}=F_{2,0}+F_{2,2}+F_{4,2}+F_{6,2}+F_{8,2}+F_{10,2}
\\\,
\\F_{10,2}=F_{8,0}+2F_{8,2}+F_{8,4}
\\F_{8,2}=F_{6,0}+2F_{6,2}+F_{6,4}
\\F_{6,2}=F_{4,0}+2F_{4,2}+F_{4,4}
\\\,
\\F_{8,4}=F_{6,2}+2F_{6,4}+F_{6,6}
\\F_{6,4}=F_{4,2}+2F_{4,4}
\\\,
\\F_{4,2}=F_{3,3}+F_{2,0}+F_{2,2}=2+2+2=6$$
So $$\begin{align}F_{12,0}&=F_{2,0}+F_{2,2}+F_{4,2}+F_{6,2}+F_{8,2}+F_{10,2}
\\&=F_{8,0}+3F_{6,0}+8F_{4,0}+21F_{4,2}+18F_{4,4}+F_{6,6}+F_{3,3}+2F_{2,0}+2F_{2,2}
\\&=F_{8,0}+3F_{6,0}+F_{4,0}+2F_{2,0}+126+36+2+2+4+4
\\&=F_{8,0}+3F_{6,0}+F_{4,0}+2F_{2,0}+174
\end{align}$$
You can then reduce further until everything is in terms of numbers.

---

**Edit:**

This method gets far too messy, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: The required probability would not be simply the sums of the probabilities of flipping the same number of heads and tail at 2,4,...12 since there will be a lot of duplicate cases and overcount. Instead we do a complimentary counting.

Comment: Yep I noticed this, it wan mentioned in a comment on the other answer, it is a bit more complicated than that. Simply adding up and using some form of inclusion exclusion isn't great either. Glad you were able to solve the problem though! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete answer, but was too long for a comment.  At any rate, it explains part (1) of your question, namely

> How do we derive the recurrence relation?

In a slight variation of the original notation, let $F_{n,k}$ denote the number of ways of obtaining $k$ as the number of heads minus the number tails after $n$ tosses.  Note that $F_{n,k}$ can take on integer values between $-n$ and $n$ (inclusive).

If we have already flipped the coin $n-1$ times, then there are only two possible ways that we can get the difference between heads and tails to be $k$ on the $n$-th toss:

1. After the $(n-1)$-st toss, we had $k-1$ more heads than tails, then got heads on the $n$-th toss.  There are $F_{n-1,k-1}$ ways for this to happen.
2. After the $(n-1)$-st toss, we had $k+1$ more heads than tails, then got tails on the $n$-th toss.  There are $F_{n-1,k+1}$ ways for this to happen.

This gives the recurrence relation
$$ F_{n,k} = F_{n-1,k-1} + F_{n-1,k+1}.$$
Note that this is slightly different than the way you originally phrased the problem.  Here, we are counting the *signed* difference between the number heads and tails, not the *absolute* difference.

> How do we use the recurrence relation to determine the probability of having an equal number of heads and tails *at some point* after the first toss?

We can now use this recurrence relation to count the different ways of obtaining a difference of $k$.  We end of with something reminiscent of Pascal's triangle:
\begin{matrix}
& \dotso & -4 & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \dotso  && \leftarrow\text{difference}\\\hline
\text{1 toss} &&&&& 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\text{2 tosses} &&&& 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
\text{3 tosses} &&& 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
\text{4 tosses} && 1 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

Indeed, this is exactly Pascal's triangle, with a bunch of zeroes added in.  It might be nice to prove that
$$ F_{n,k} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $n$ and $k$ have different parity, and} \\
\displaystyle\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}(n+k)} & \text{if $n$ and $k$ have the same parity.} \\
\end{cases}
$$
Note that we could have come to the same conclusion by noting that the number of heads after $n$ tosses is binomially distributed, from which we could deduce the formula above.

At this point, we have a formula for computing $F_{n,k}$ for any $n$ and $k$, which we can use to compute probabilities.  Unfortunately, there is quite a bit of redundancy, so the computation is a little tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the posts! After understanding how the recursion is formed I managed to solve the problem by using complementary counting. Since the "same number" of flips for heads and tails can occur anywhere it is difficult to use a constructive counting method with PIE. Rather, let all $F_{n,o} = 0$ for all $n$ and proceed with building up the recursion. We can then add up all $F_{12,k}$ where k is an even not equal to zero to find the number of ways to flip 12 coins without having the same number of heads and tails anywhere. Subtracting this from $2^{12}$ and dividing by $2^{12}$ yeilds the correct answer. The recursion is not too bad as we only need to consider even k for an even n and odd k for an odd n. Also building the recursion from bottom-up is considerably faster then top-down.